# An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code while Registering

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I am getting following exception in my code.

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code.
>
> Additional information: The entity type user is not part of the model for the current context.

Following is my Register Controller.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Registration2.Controllers
{
    public class userController : Controller
    {
        // GET: user
        public ActionResult Index() => View();
        public ActionResult Register() => View();

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Register(Registration2.user U)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                using (MyDatabase2Entities dc = new MyDatabase2Entities())
                {
                    //you should check duplicate registration here 
                    // dc.users.Add

                    dc.users.Add(U);
                    dc.SaveChanges();
                    ModelState.Clear();
                    U = null;
                    ViewBag.Message = "Successfully Registration Done";
                }
            }
            return View(U);
        }
    }
}
```

I am totally new to ASP.net and MVC so please tell if i miss anything, i will post it here.

Comment: If you right click on your Data Model, and select "Validate", do you get any errors?

Comment: Wrap your code in a `try-catch` block and show us the exception message and stack trace and we will be able to help you more.

Comment: Also why are you setting User to null, when it gets returned to the View after a Save?

Comment: Also, "U" should be lower case (best participate for parameter names). I prefer to use the name of the class in lowercase. So rather than "U", use "user".

Comment: @CarlProthman: yes i removed U to null, but i dont know how validate data Model, can you please tell me how to do it?

Comment: In design mode, open up the Entity Data Model, right click anywhere on the background and select "Validate". https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cc716694%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: @CarlProthman: No error Found after Validation

Comment: Then do what Jurgen suggested and post the complete exception.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The entity type user is not part of the model for the current context.

This is the salient part. Is the User object part of your MyDatabase2Entities context? It appears not.

Comment: yes you are correct here but how to make it part of the current context?

Comment: Right click on Data Model and select Update from Database, after the wizard comes up, make sure to select the User table.  HTH  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cc716697%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: @CarlProthman:Thanks alot mate, you actually solved my issue, but this was the only answer that i can accept

Comment: No worries. Glad this fixed your issue.